# Use of the verb "sich auseinandersetzen"

Tags: word-usage, verb, grammaticality, passive, impersonal-constructions

Is the sentence correct?

> Es wurde empfohlen, dass sich frühzeitig mit dem Thema auseinandergesetzt wird.

Is "sich auseinandergesetzt wird" a correct usage of the verb? I would rather use

> Es wurde empfohlen, sich frühzeitig mit dem Thema auseinanderzusetzen.

Comment: Smith, welcome! Could you please clarify what you mean by „sounds weird“? Without more details, this may be seen as *proofreading request*, which would then be closed by the community. I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [ask] and then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: It's passive voice vs active voice. A matter of taste or style.

Comment: I personally find the passive phrase a little constructed. It is used like that in speech and writing, yes,but it does indeed sound rather, er... unusual.I would greatly prefer the second sentence, even if some will tell you that the first one is fine. IMO, it isn't.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: The passive phrase sounds so unusual to me too.

Comment: The passive form is the kind of construct you might find in legal and official texts, but is not something you (or, IMO, anyone else) should use. "Unusual" does not express it, I guess. "Clunky" expresses it much better, perhaps.

Comment: I love German, not only but also for such stuff... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es handelt sich um das Passiv eines echt reflexiven Verbs (*sich* bleibt im Passiv erhalten und der Satz ist ohne Subjekt). Es lassen sich leicht Korpusbelege finden:

> **HMP06/NOV.02496** Ich freue mich immer, wenn sich mit meiner Leistung auseinandergesetzt wird.
>
> **PHH/W16.00070** Ich verweise zugleich auf den jeweiligen Verfassungsschutzbericht, in dem sich mit dieser Frage auseinandergesetzt wird.
>
> **PHH/W18.00062** Aber es gibt auch einen Grund, warum [...] es nicht einfach gleichgültig ist, ob sich hier, im Bayerischen Landtag oder an anderer Stelle damit auseinandergesetzt wird.
>
> **RHZ09/JAN.04087** Am Sonntag, 11. Januar, gibt es um 10 Uhr in der Gemeinde einen Gottesdienst und Kindergottesdienst, in denen sich mit dem vorgenannten Film auseinandergesetzt wird.
>
> **T14/JUN.00398** Die Grünen wollen zudem, dass sich mit der militanten Neonaziszene im Land insgesamt auseinandergesetzt wird.

Wie die Belege zeigen, ist eine Ersetzung durch eine Infinitivkonstruktion nicht immer möglich. Auch ein Aktiv scheint mir nicht immer passend, da ein subjektloses Passiv noch unpersönlicher als ein Aktiv mit *man* wirkt. Deshalb klingt folgender Satz für mich schlechter als das oben zitierte Beispiel:

> Ich verweise zugleich auf den jeweiligen Verfassungsschutzbericht, in dem **man** sich mit dieser Frage auseinandersetzt.

Comment: Nice examples; fair comment.

Comment: Ich verweise zugleich auf den jeweiligen Verfassungsschutzbericht, der sich mit dieser Frage auseinandersetzt.

Comment: Wenn einem die Konstruktion nicht gefällt, findet man immer eine Paraphrase. Ich wollte nur zeigen, daß die in der Frage gegebene Ersetzbarkeit durch eine Infinitivkonstruktion sowie die immer naheliegende Ersetzung des Passivs durch ein Aktiv nicht immer gilt.